# Dynamically set a Swiper JS param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

Im trying to dynamically set the eventsTarget inside the mousewheel object in Swiper dependant on changes to a data property using Vue.js. Essentially when disableBodyScroll is true the carousel can be scrolled via the eventsTarget:html else use the default swiper container:

```
  data() {
    return {
      disableBodyScroll: false,
    }
  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.initSwiper()
  },

 methods: {
    initSwiper() {
      const vm = this

      if (this.$refs?.carousel) {
        this.carousel = new SwiperCore(this.$refs.carousel, {
          mousewheel: {
            eventsTarget: this.disableBodyScroll ? 'html' : 'container',
            releaseOnEdges: true,
            thresholdDelta: 1,
          },
          freeMode: this.mousewheelScroll,
          freeModeSticky: this.mousewheelScroll,
          on: {
            reachEnd: (swiper) => {
              vm.disableBodyScroll = false
              swiper.params.mousewheel.eventsTarget = 'container'
              swiper.update()
            },
            reachBeginning: (swiper) => {
              vm.disableBodyScroll = false
              swiper.params.mousewheel.eventsTarget = 'container'
              swiper.update()
            },
          },
        })
      }
    },
  },
```

I have some other methods that change the disableBodyScroll data property.
I've tried the above code without success and it remains the same.
I've been able to get it to work via adding a watcher and destroying the carousel before initialising it again

```
watch: {
  disableBodyScroll(newVal) {
    if (this.carousel) {
      this.carousel.destroy(true, false);
      this.initSwiper();
    }
  },
```

However this sets the swiper carousel back to the beginning state and isn't a good UX.
On reaching the end and beginning of the slides I've tried explicitly setting the eventsTarget and using update() which has also been unsuccessful.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Swiper JS's parameters are generally updatable by using `.setAttribute()` as noted in [the official doc](https://swiperjs.com/element#updating-parameters).
However, this does not apply to parameters for [modules](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#modules), such as Mousewheel module.

Fortunately, same effect is still achievable without using any attribute updates.

## Answer

Make wrapper element and assign for `mousewheel.eventsTarget`. Set element's size as big as html body(i.g. `100vh`) or as big as container, upon `.bodyScroll` data property.

```html
<template>
  <div class="wheel-control" :style="wheelControlStyle">
    <div class="swiper" ref="carousel">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button @click="updateEventsTarget">change mousewheel eventstarget</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      bodyScroll: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    wheelControlStyle() {
      // if user should be scrolling on body, just make it as big as body.
      return { height: this.bodyScroll ? '100vh' : 'auto' }
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.initSwiper()
  },
  methods: {
    initSwiper() {
      console.log('refs', this.$refs)
      if (this.$refs?.carousel) {
        this.$carousel = new Swiper(this.$refs.carousel as HTMLElement, {
          mousewheel: {
            eventsTarget: '.wheel-control',
            releaseOnEdges: true
          }
        })
      }
    },
    updateEventsTarget() {
      console.log('updating')
      if (!this.$carousel) return
      this.bodyScroll = !this.bodyScroll
    }
  }
```

here's working demo on my Github: https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/77486089-vue-swiper-dynamic-parameters